# Return SCOPE_IDENTITY() without using CreateParam

Tags: asp-classic, vbscript, adodb

I'm trying this but getting an error `ADODB.Recordset error '800a0e78' Operation is not allowed when the object is closed.` on the line with this code `If ScopeID.EOF Then`

Please do not answer to use the `CreateParam` method, Looking for a solution without this method. Thanks.

```
<%  
    set Cmd = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
    Cmd.ActiveConnection = conn

    Cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO TABLE (NAME) VALUES ('test')  SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() AS ID"
    Cmd.CommandType = 1
    Cmd.CommandTimeout = 0
    Cmd.Prepared = true

    Set ScopeID = Cmd.Execute()

    If ScopeID.EOF Then
        Response.Write "There was an Error in your request, Please try again"
        Response.End
    Else
        ID= ScopeID(0).Value
    End IF

    ScopeID.Close
    Set ScopeID = Nothing
    Set Cmd = Nothing

    Response.Write ID

%>
```

Comment: Should your connection be set with a `Set Cmd.ActiveConnection = conn`?

Comment: Nope, works fine without the `Set` part.

Comment: Check reply from Robert Wagner in the below link

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/304281/classic-asp-getting-scope-identity-value-from-sql2005

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Applying `.NextRecordSet()` after the command did the trick:

```
<%  
    set Cmd = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
    Cmd.ActiveConnection = conn

    Cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO TABLE (NAME) VALUES ('test')  SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() AS ID"
    Cmd.CommandType = 1
    Cmd.CommandTimeout = 0
    Cmd.Prepared = true

    Set ScopeID = Cmd.Execute()
            ScopeID.NextRecordSet() // <---- Fix

    If ScopeID.EOF Then
        Response.Write "There was an Error in your request, Please try again"
        Response.End
    Else
        ID= ScopeID(0).Value
    End IF

    ScopeID.Close
    Set ScopeID = Nothing
    Set Cmd = Nothing

    Response.Write ID

%>
```

Comment: Set ScopeID = ScopeID.NextRecordSet() is what did it for me

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
Cmd.CommandText = "SET NOCOUNT ON; INSERT INTO TABLE (NAME) VALUES ('test'); SET NOCOUNT OFF; SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() AS ID"
```

As I understand it, SQL Server returns a (empty) record-set for the actual insert statement if it is not "hidden" by SET NOCOUNT ON. I think the error message refers to the record-set being closed, and not the connection.

Answer (score 1):

If you are running a modern version of SQL Server (2005 on wards I think) you can use the output clause:

```
Cmd.CommandText = "insert into [dbo].[test] (name) output inserted.id values ('test')"
```

Answer (score 0):

Is your connection open? It seems like that's what the error message is complaining about. You can't execute a command against a closed connection.

Comment: You would say the the error for not having an open connection would be on the `Set ScopeID = Cmd.Execute()` line?

Comment: I believe the error message sounds like a closed connection.  Does this error go away when you explicitly open your connection?

Comment: The same message is given for a closed recordset. In this case the query does not return an open recordset, hence the fault when trying to assess EOF.

Answer (score 0):

Split your query into two parts:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE (NAME) VALUES ('test'); SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() AS ID
```

Notice the `;`. I think the second part of your query is not executed.